# How to combine multiple response , where function take different parameter, to give different response from a single function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

how do I combine multiple response, where function takes a different parameter, to give different response from a single function, I want all response should be combined in a single array.

```
const data = [
{id:1,name:"currency"},
{id:1,name:"merchant"},
{id:1,name:"broker"},
]

data.map(i=>{
   getData(i.name)
})
getData(name){
const response = getResponsedata(name);
if (response?.data && response?.status === 200) {
            setData(response.data);
  }
}

getResponsedata(name){
  try{
const response = await axios.get(`/api/data/${name}`)
return response
}
```

here it gives me a different array, I want all in one

Comment: I don't think this question is clear. Are you trying to make multiple calls to the api and you want those multiple responses in a single array? In that case @andy 's answer is the solution. Instead of the console.log at point you can modify the data in whatever format you need.

Answer (score 0):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Take an array of promises and wait for them to resolve (or not).

```js
const data = [
  { id:1, name:'currency' },
  { id:1, name:'merchant' },
  { id:1, name:'broker' },
];

// Return the name after two seconds
function mockFetch(name) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(name), 2000);
  });
};

// Create an array of promises
const promises = data.map(obj => mockFetch(obj.name));

// Wait for all the data to resolve - an array is returned
Promise.all(promises).then(data => console.log(data));
```

You can also use async/await:

```
async getData() {
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(data);
}

getData();
```

Comment: no, i want response to be combined, not the data name.

Comment: It's just an example based off the code you provided. `Promise.all` is the solution you want.